# Why did L not prevent the report of Kira's tests in the police database if he already concluded he must have had access to such information?

Tags: anime, death-note

For some reason, the genius L only said not to report that information to the media. But in the previous episode he had already concluded that Kira had to have access to police information.

**Episode 3**: L concludes that Kira can control the time of death and is flaunting it, concluding to himself that Kira must have access to police information (they were suspecting he was a student and he previously accessed this internally reported information).

> L: But something's not right. As soon as we began to suspect that Kira might be a student, the pacing of the killings changed. As if to contradict that theory. Coincidence? No. Too convenient. This can only mean that Kira has access to police information. It's obvious now. This is a direct challenge to me.

**Episode 4**: Hacking into the notes for the ongoing investigation, Light discovers that L suspects they were tests and doesn't want this information reported to the media.

> L: We can't release details of these men's deaths to the media [...] I have reason to believe that Kira was performing some kind of "test" using these criminals. And if that's the case, we'd only be giving him the results of this information if we put it public.

I missed this on my previous rewatches. Small inconsistency, isn't it?

Comment: The folks at the anime/manga stack exchange might have more insight, there may be some information that could be gleaned from the manga.

Comment: @Aww_Geez [OP has since cross-posted this there](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/58033/35679).

Comment: @F1Krazy What's going on here? I recall episode 3 was strictly about time of deaths while episode 4 was about the ... shinigami love apples? What's the relation between these 2 sets of killings?

Comment: Don't ask me. It's been years since I watched the anime and I don't remember it clearly enough to give you an answer to that. If you have a separate question, consider posting it as one.